# show MKPinAnnotationView not simultaneously

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkpinannotationview

Hi I want to show `MKPinAnnotationView` based on the value of latitude and longitude stored in an array, but I want that all pins should not appear simultaneously. It should be one after another, means **when one pin appears after some delay another pin appear**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use NSTimer to get achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) to get it done :
Something like this :

```
-(Void)viewDidLoad{
       _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(_timerFired)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
}
- (void)_timerFired
{
   //Code to add the Annotation
   // Completed the annotation, then nil the Timer 
    if (_timer != nil && <annotationArray_reached_end>)
    {
      [_timer invalidate];
      _timer = nil;
    }
}
```